# Adding thermal radiation to schematic heat element (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am making a schematic for my thesis to show (and calculate) the heat generation in a certain grinding process (GRIN01).

I've managed to create the following:
[image]

However, I would also like to show the thermal radiation coming from the heating element (the thick black bar in the middle). Something like this:
[image].

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0pt,0pt);
    \coordinate (A) at (-75pt,-30pt);
    \coordinate (B) at (-75pt,30pt);
    \coordinate (C) at (75pt,30pt);
    \coordinate (D) at (75pt,-30pt);
    \draw[fill=white, draw = black](A) -- (B) --node[above]{GRIN01}node[below]{$T_{\mathrm{grin}}\quad V$} (C) -- (D)--cycle;
    \draw[->](-125pt,0)node[left]{$T_{\mathrm{in}}$} -- node[above]{$\phi_{\mathrm{v,in}}$}node[below]{$X_{\mathrm{in}}$}(-75pt,0);
    \draw[->](75pt,0) -- node[above]{$\phi_{\mathrm{v,out}}$}node[below]{$X_{\mathrm{out}}$}(125pt,0)node[right]{$T_{\mathrm{out}}$};
    \draw[line width=3pt](-25pt,-10pt) -- node[below]{$\phi_{\mathrm{w}}$}(25pt,-10pt);
    \draw[](-25pt,-30pt) -- (-25pt,-10pt) -- (25pt,-10pt) -- (25pt,-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option using `decorations.markings`...

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    Heat/.style={
         draw=none,
         inner color=red,%you can erase this line
         outer color=yellow, %you can erase this line
            postaction={
                decorate,
                rounded corners=2pt,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 6pt and 55pt step 9pt
                    with {
                        \draw[-Triangle,red,line width=0.5pt](0,0)
                            --++(0.1,0.1)
                            --++(-0.2,0.1)
                            --++(0.1,0.1)
                            --++(0,0.2);
                    }
                }
            }
      }
]
    \coordinate (O) at (0pt,0pt);
    \coordinate (A) at (-75pt,-30pt);
    \coordinate (B) at (-75pt,30pt);
    \coordinate (C) at (75pt,30pt);
    \coordinate (D) at (75pt,-30pt);
    \draw[fill=white, draw = black](A) -- (B) --node[above]{GRIN01}node[below]{$T_{\mathrm{grin}}\quad V$} (C) -- (D)--cycle;
    \draw[->](-125pt,0)node[left]{$T_{\mathrm{in}}$} -- node[above]{$\phi_{\mathrm{v,in}}$}node[below]{$X_{\mathrm{in}}$}(-75pt,0);
    \draw[->](75pt,0) -- node[above]{$\phi_{\mathrm{v,out}}$}node[below]{$X_{\mathrm{out}}$}(125pt,0)node[right]{$T_{\mathrm{out}}$};
    \draw[line width=3pt](-25pt,-10pt) -- node[below]{$\phi_{\mathrm{w}}$}(25pt,-10pt);
    \draw[Heat](-25pt,-10pt) -- ++(0,4pt) -- ++(50pt,0) -- ++(0,-4pt); % LINE FOR HEAT SHAPE AND ARROWS
    \draw(-25pt,-30pt) -- (-25pt,-10pt) -- (25pt,-10pt) -- (25pt,-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 @ThomasIke If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
     heat/.style={FireBrick,thick,-Latex, decoration={coil,aspect=0},decorate}
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=DarkSeaGreen,DarkSeaGreen](0,0) rectangle (2,0.3);
    \foreach \x in {0.2,0.6,1.0,1.4,1.8} {
      \draw[heat](\x,0.3)--++(0,0.5);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```